# Insert into row if value exists in a different table

Tags: sql, database, sql-update

I have two tables:

**Users**:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
|        UserId       |    ValueToUpdate    |
+---------------------+---------------------+
|          1          |                     |
|          2          |                     |
|          3          |                     |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

**Subscribers**:

```
+---------------------+
|        UserId       |
+---------------------+
|          1          |
|          2          |
+---------------------+
```

I need to write a SQL query that will insert some value into the `Users` table, column (`ValueToUpdate`) if the user id in the `Users` table exists in the `Subscribers` table.

Essentially I'm looking for something like this

```
 UPDATE Users 
 SET ValueToUpdate = "some value" 
 WHERE (UserId from the Users table exists in the Subscribers table);
```

How could I achieve this?

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag your the question appropriately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using an `exists` clause:

```
 UPDATE Users u
 SET ValueToUpdate = 'some value'
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Subscribers S WHERE s.userid = u.userid);
```